# Internet Explorer 11 does not open local three.js, not even with local server

Tags: three.js, localhost, internet-explorer-11

That includes three.js examples too, while they do open online.
I tried both python and node.js servers, it receives the file list, but when the HTML is clicked, the screen remains black. They open fine in Firefox, Chrome, SeaMonkey etc. Of course, it's IE 11 the problem, NOT three.js.

Any ideas how to make IE 11 open local three.js files?

Comment: Does it work if you download the repo and then execute `npm install` and `npm start` in the root directory? The servers runs under http://localhost:8080

Comment: Download what repository, three.js? I did download the three.js-dev.zip then tried 'npm install' and 'npm start' (tried alone and with the zip file name and got errors) on the root of the partition, and no server started (no response at localhost:8080). I'm not using git BTW.

Comment: I extracted the zip, then run 'npm install three.js-dev' and aside the other errors incl. 'no repository' it mentioned three.js 93 in the end. 
'npm run' didn't raise errors, but still no server. I don't have a clue what that "mystic" instruction actually run...

Comment: Try it with this link: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 11 started to run local three.js files directly (with drag and drop the HTML file) after I did the following:

Internet Options/Advanced/Security
selected:
"Allow active content to run in files on My Computer" and rebooted the computer.

But I found out that IE 11 has only ***partial*** WEBGL support, as it only supports WEBGL 0.94 instead of WEBGL 1.0 required for THREE.js.

Comparison:

***Firefox 60***

[image: Firefox v60]

***Chrome v67***
[image: CHROME v67]

***IE 11.096***

[image]

(According to online test https://browserleaks.com/webgl )

As a consequence, it won't run many three.js examples (and other implementations) whether locally or online. Here is a subset:

webgl_postprocessing_crossfade

webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_lambert

webgl_lines_fat

webaudio_sandbox

webaudio_timing

webaudio_visualizer

webgl_depth_texture - "NO SUPPORT"

webgl_geometry_minecraft

webgl_gpgpu_birds

webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu

webgl_kinect

webgl_loader_amf

webgl_loader_collada_kinematics

webgl_loader_draco

webgl_loader_gltf

webgl_loader_gltf_extensions

(from https://threejs.org/examples/ )