# THREE is undefined in IE11 but not in Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, three.js, internet-explorer-11

I can't get the code to work in IE11 even though it works perfectly fine in other browsers (like Chrome).

I've found something on codepen.io that is perfect for what I'm trying to show. (https://codepen.io/iMax723/pen/JXMNdv)
The problem is that as soon as I try to open it with the IE nothing shows up.

- I checked if IE even supports Three.js and it does - but only partly (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50880630/8428325).
- I even checked if WebGL is supported by going on this site: https://get.webgl.org/ - and it does
- I tried messing with the security settings (activated ActiveX and opening files from my local machine and so on) - didn't work.

  ```
  <body>
      <script>
      THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape = (function() {
          //Code})();
      </script>
  </body>
  ```

This is the message I get when using the console: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/xyf5fs0y(v=vs.94) --> in the THREE... line

Comment: It's the first line in my script tag (THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape...)

Answer (score 0):

> THREE is undefined in IE11 but not in Chrome

Try to change the JavaScript script import order, after adding the JQuery reference, you could add the custom JavaScript script and use the THREE.

Code as below (please check your code, you add the JQuery reference twice):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="three-container"></div>
    <div id="instructions">
        MAX HUANG
    </div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r75/three.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/175711/TextGeometry.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/175711/FontUtils.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/175711/pnltri.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/175711/droid_sans_bold.typeface.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/175711/bas.js'></script>
    <script src="Scripts/index.js"></script>

    <script>
        THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape = (function () {
            var pnlTriangulator = new PNLTRI.Triangulator();
            return function triangulateShape(contour, holes) {
                return pnlTriangulator.triangulate_polygon([contour].concat(holes));
            };
        })();</script>
</body>
```

The above code works well on my side (using IE 11.116.18362.0 version), but it need 3~6 seconds to load the Javascript and display the animation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work either. The window is still blank.

Comment: Try to use F12 developer Network tools to check whether the reference load success, and use Console Tools to check whether it contains some error?

Comment: What's your IE 11 browser version? you could try to create a new application to test  the above code, whether it works well. if still not working, you could try to [reset the IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) or upgrade the IE browser to  the 11.116.18362.0 version.

Comment: My current Version is 11.437.17763.0
I exported Max Huangs code and it works perfectly fine on my machine... But there is no diffenrence in the code.